# docker watchtower - pull access denied from private docker repository

Tags: docker, docker-watchtower

I've beent trying to setup a automatic docker pulling environment.

Here's my commands.

-starting app container

`$docker run -d index.docker.io/<username>/<reponame>`

-starting watchtower with config.json

`$docker run -d --name watchtower -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock: -v /$HOME/.docker/config.json:/$HOME/config.json: containrrr/watchtower --run-once`

-/$HOME/config.json

```
{
    "auths": {
        "index.docker.io/<username>/<reponame>": {
            "auth": "<token>"
        }
    }
}
```

-and this is a response from watchtower

`Error response from daemon: pull access denied for <username>/<reponame> repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'`

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to read watchtower docs very carefully. these links might help.
https://containrrr.dev/watchtower/usage-overview/
https://containrrr.dev/watchtower/private-registries/

And answer for the question, here's how i cracked it.

- in docker-compose or docker run command parameter,config.json, you have to explicit full repository prefix and tag(ex:index.docker.io/<username>/<repository>:<tag>, maybe tag is not mandatory.).
- and for the config.json reference, put `/<path>/config.json:/config.json:` instead.
- you'll see a format error if you put your docker auth token in config.json. use `echo -n '<username:<token>' | base64` to generate the token and put it in the auth value in config.json

Comment: I can confirm adding `index.docker.io` before `< username>/<repository>` in my `docker run` command helped to resolve the issue. I have no words. I really appreciate your answer.